# Не работает метод сode у event (e.code) в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, события

У меня есть обработчик события onKeyDown. По нажатию на клавишу, запускается функция, где в проверке я смотрю была ли нажата клавиша space, но код не работает.
Ошибка:

- App.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'code')

Код:

```
  const stateHex=(event)=>{
    if(true){
      if(event.code==='Space'){
        console.log('dasd')
      }


 <div className="App" tabIndex={0} onKeyDown={()=>stateHex()} >
```

Comment: Так вы в фунцию ничего не передаете, измените `onKeyDown={(e)=>stateHex(e)}` и почитайте про `console.log`. Так же уберите if (true) - это бессмыслица

Comment: if true - часть другого функционала, вместо true должен стоять статус, который генерирует true или  false в зависимости от определенной ситуации. А так, спасибо большое, глупая ошибка..

Answer (score 0):

```js
const stateHex=(event) => {
   if(event.code === 'Space') {
     console.log('dasd')
   }
}


 <div className="App" tabIndex={0} onKeyDown={stateHex} />
```